# Splitting an unordered list into multiple divs using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list comprised of little bits of HTML (images, styled text, forms, etc.). The number of items in the list is a variable between 1 and 10. How can I create a pagination system such that all the list items are shown in one DIV if there are 5 or less items, and another DIV is created and filled with the overflow if there are more than 5 items?

For example here is a list with an arbitrary number of elements (in this case, seven):

```
 <ul>
      <li><img src="photo.jpg" /></li>
      <li><strong>TEXT TEXT TEXT</strong></li>
      <li><img src="another_photo.jpg" /></li>
      <li><strong>MORE TEXT TEXT TEXT</strong></li>
      <li><a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello There');">Say Hello!</a></li>
      <li>MORE STUFF</li>
      <li>YET EVEN MORE STUFF</li>
 </ul>
```

And this would be the resulting DIVs

```
 <div id="first_div">
      <ul>
           <li><img src="photo.jpg" /></li>
           <li><strong>TEXT TEXT TEXT</strong></li>
           <li><img src="another_photo.jpg" /></li>
           <li><strong>MORE TEXT TEXT TEXT</strong></li>
           <li><a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello There');">Say Hello!</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="second_div">
      <ul>
           <li>MORE STUFF</li>
           <li>YET EVEN MORE STUFF</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you what you want in pretty short order. It ensures that the two new DIVs land in the DOM where the original UL used to be. It also uses pure jQ selector power rather than loops and counters.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/3cRZw/1/

**Code:**

```
var UL = $( 'ul' ),
    upperLIs = UL.find( 'li:gt(4)' ), //get list of LIs above index 4 (above 5th)
    DIV1 = $( '<div>' ).attr( 'id', 'first_div' ); //we will definitely need this first DIV

//Get the first DIV into the DOM right before the UL before any movement of UL
//Ensure same DOM placement as we started with
UL.before( DIV1 );

//Check for LIs above index 4
if( upperLIs.length )
{
    //Add those LIs to a new UL
    //which itself is added to a new DIV
    //which itself is added after DIV1
    DIV1.after(
        $( '<div>' )
            .attr( 'id', 'second_div' )
            .append(
                $( '<ul>' )
                    .append( upperLIs )
            )
    );
}

//Move the original UL to DIV1 with it's remaining 5 LIs
DIV1.append( UL );
```

**Edit:** edited code to add explanatory comments

Comment: Nice work, just what I was planning. Not many people seem to know about `gt()`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `<ul>` in a div.  Then grab the last 5 `<li>` and append them to a new `<ul>` inside a new `<div>`:

```
var ul = $("#myList").wrap($("<div>").attr("id", "first_div"));
$("<div><ul>").attr("id", "second_div").insertAfter("#first_div")
    .append(ul.find("li:gt(4)"));
```

Comment: I like that you used `.wrap()`. Combining that with the `:gt(4)` selector I used would make a really good answer! (off to edit)

Comment: @JAAulde - Yes, I agree.  `:gt(4)` is a bit more tidy than `.slice(5,10)`.  Updated to include your suggestion.

Comment: :)  I am gonna leave my answer alone for now as `.wrap()` operates differently than I remembered. But definitely well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lis=$('ul li');
var divuid=1;
var i=0;
while(lis.length>i){
    var lisPart=lis.slice(i,i+4);
    i+=4;
    $('<div id="div'+(divuid++)+'"></div>').append(lisPart).appendTo($('#my_container'));
}
$('ul li').remove();
```

shot in the dark, haven't tested it yet... something like this though?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with "lisPart" (and you forgot `var`), and it doesn't modify "lis" in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit verbose bit this should do it (untested):

```
$(function() {
   var threshold = 5;

   // get the original list
   var $ul = $("ul");

   // create the first container
   var $div = $("<div id='first_div'><ul /></div>").appendTo('body');

   $("li", $ul).each(function(i) {
      if(i < threshold) {
         $("ul", $div).append($(this));
      }
      else {
         $overflowDiv = $("#second_div");

         // create the second container if it doesn't already exists
         if(!$overflowDiv.length) {
            var $overflowDiv = $("<div id='second_div'><ul /></div>").appendTo('body');
         }
         $("ul", $overflowDiv).append($(this));
      }
   });

   // remove the (now empty) list
   $ul.remove();

});
```